# How can I go to an older version of schema?

Tags: database, django, heroku, django-south, schema-migration

I have a Postgre SQL database in Heroku. I've had some problems. I needed to delete some local migration files and create brand new schema migration files (which worked) that had all migrations included.

A relationship from this new schema migration file already existed in my Heroku database and when I try to migrate I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "quizzer_speaker" already exists
```

How can I make Heroku actually do the migration? Or how can I make it go to a previous version where that relation didn't exist, so I can just migrate without problems?

Comment: What tool are you using for schema migration? South?

Comment: Yes, is south what I'm using